# Configuring cron.hourly

Tags: linux, cron

I am unable to configure a cron job to run by placing it in /etc/cron.hourly folder.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

The file under cron.hourly is :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   40 2010-07-26 14:52 check -> /usr/local/xxxx/check-interface.bash
```

Permissions on the file :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K 2010-09-13 11:22 /usr/local/xxxx/check-interface.bash
```

There seems to be no errors reported in the var/log/cron logfile. No mention of the script is done. :(

Comment: Are you sure crond is running?

Comment: yep, i restart the daemon after the changes manually.

Comment: `chmod +x /usr/local/xxxx`

Comment: What version of Cron do you have (it's ok if you say what distribution you have)? Some versions have rules for naming files in `/etc/cron.*`. Is `check` the actual name of the symlink? Does the script run correctly if you run it manually? Are you sure it's not running and just having no visible effect?

Comment: Is this a debian system, per chance?

Comment: no this was on fedora core. Script as mentioned below was having a problem.( was loading relative paths rather than absolute :) - hence even though the script ran "as-is" but running it via symlink was an issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to isolate the problem, move /usr/local/xxxx/check-interface.bash to /etc/cron.hourly/check , and then see if it runs.

If the script does run, then the problem is caused by an ownership/permissions or related issue which is preventing cron from executing scripts at /usr/local/xxxx/*.

If the script does not run, then the problem is most likely with your script itself.

As another sanity check, replace the contents of `/usr/local/xxxx/check-interface.bash` with something dead simple, like:

```
date > /tmp/check-interfaces.log 2>&1
```

And then see if /tmp/check-interfaces.log is actually being populated by your cronjob. If it does work, then the problem must be with your original script.

Comment: On several distros, `run-parts` explicitly skips files that have a period in them as they may have been generated by a package update. Maybe that's what he's running up against.

Comment: Care to elaborate on that please ? I am not sure what you mean by having a period in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just want to confirm that as [Shadur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10232/configuring-cron-hourly#comment13390_10242) has mentioned earlier, the issue lies in the fact that by default the "run-parts" application used by cron will run only commands that contain only ASCII letters, `_`, and `-`.
From the official man page:

```
   If  neither the --lsbsysinit option nor the --regex option is given then the names must consist entirely of ASCII upper- and lower-case letters, ASCII digits,
   ASCII underscores, and ASCII minus-hyphens.
```